# jquery: Count and append json response to existing ul list in html

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am trying to append my json response to the ul class but it keeps giving me an error.
This is the response I get:

`{"joineddate":"2020-01-01", "joineddate":"2020-01-02","joineddate":"2020-01-03"}`

I want to add the dates to an ul class "joineddate"

```
$.ajax({
    url:URL,
     method: 'POST',
     data: {
        joineddate: 1,
        customerid: customerid
     },
    success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        var val = JSON.parse(data);
        var output = '<ul class="joineddate">';
        $.each(data, function(key, val){
            output += '<li>';
            output += '<a href="#">'+val.consult_date + '</a>';
            output += '</li>';              
        });
        output += '</ul>';
        $('.joineddate').html(output);
     },
     error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }

  });
```

Comment: What is the output of  `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: Hi Anjana, the response is {"joineddate":"2020-01-01", "joineddate":"2020-01-02","joineddate":"2020-01-03"}

Comment: A JSON object can not have duplicate keys (in your case: `joineddate` is the key ). Can you try to get a JSON array like: `{ "joineddate": ["2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03"] }`

Comment: `[{"joineddate":"2020-05-12"},{"joineddate":"2020-05-11"}]`. I've got it in this format now. Do you think I can do something with this?

Comment: Thank you Anjana.. I was able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url:URL,
     method: 'POST',
     data: {
        appointment: 1,
        mrn: MRN
     },
    success: function(data){            
        var vals = JSON.parse(data);
        var output = '<ul class="joineddate">';
        $.each(vals, function(key, val){
            output += '<li>';
            output += '<a href="#">'+vals[key].joineddate + '</a>';
            output += '</li>';

        });
        output += '</ul>';
        console.log(output);
        $('.joineddate').html(output);
     },
     error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert(request.responseText);
        }

  });
```